# SharePoint 2013 global navigation update

Tags: sharepoint, navigation

I've inherited a SharePoint 2013 site and I need to change a link. I've located the link in a file called GlobalNavigation.html, but I understand I need to publish that now. It is a header across the entire site and when I look to edit the main page hoping it would provide some guidance, all I see is the page as users see it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Tricky without knowing more. If you use chrome: Hit F12 and see the source of what is actually being rendered. If your link changes to not work: Try <shift>+<f5> to reload the page and all components. Sometimes changes do not become visible because the old page is cached in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, navigation is set up in **Site Settings > Navigation**, not with an HTML file. If your site does not use that approach and has been customised with a non-standard technique, maybe applied by a third party tool or a consultant, that will be hard to troubleshoot remotely.

Note that navigation set up with Site Settings > Navigation can be inherited by sub-sites and changes need to be made at the site collection level.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it doesn't match what we're seeing on the main pages, so I'm sure it's custom. There's also a pair of buttons. What tool would I use to edit and republish? I don't see any Visual Studio installations on any of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

The links were set up in an html file under style library. All I need to do is upload the new file.

I now need to get permissions to do so, but the original owner is gone for me to get approval.